# Does base64_encode() Values for Same String Differ?

Tags: php, string, encoding, hash, base64

I want to use a column that contains the string encoded with `base64_encode()` function as primary key. But I couldn't get to learn that if same string gets different values when encoded with `base64_encode()`.

Should I check the key existence with using encoded string in sql queries or should I get all values from DB and decode them one by one to see if that key exist? That depends on knowing if `base64_encode()` function always creates the same output for given string. Does it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes - Base64 turns binary data to a string using a safe subset of ASCII

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the function base64_encode() always produces the same output for a given string. This is called deterministic function or deterministic algorithm.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm

Comment: "... given a particular input, will always produce the same output". thanks for the source URL.

Answer (score 3):

base64_encode is consistent and returns the same values for the same input

Answer (score 3):

base64 encoding always encodes data the same way, note that original encoding of string can yield in different base64 encoding.

Why on earth anyone would use a base64 encoded strings as PK beats me though

Comment: yeah, it beats me too. I guess I won't have a problem since I intend to use only base64_encode() and base64_decode() with no parameters etc.

Comment: PK means passkey, not to be confused with PW or password. https://blog.1password.com/passkeys-vs-passwords-differences/